# "hg commit -m 'My changes' " error

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I follow [this article](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/quickstart) to create a repository using Mercurial:

```
$ hg clone http://selenic.com/repo/hello
$ cd hello
$ hg add a.txt
$ hg commit -m 'My changes'
```

but when i use `hg commit -m 'My changes'`, it shows error :

```
abort: changes':
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: What happens when you use double quotes instead?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your single quotes aren't behaving as such, which would hint that you're using a different character. Are you using the standard straight single quote?

Answer (score 0):

Single-quoted strings need to be supported by your shell.  Double quotes should work.  For example, the Windows shell only supports double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply do

```
hg commit
```

it will show you the editor, where you can type in your commit message.

As others have pointed out, though, double quotes should do the trick too.